# How to get setting value of another project in multi-project build

Tags: scala, sbt

I`m not sure that I get right the concept of sbt workflow. I have multi-project structure of an arbitrary depth in my build.sbt
Now I want to define task which can show me library dependencies of project current subprojects depends on. Or, in common: is there any way to get setting value of another project?

I`m trying to do somthing like this:

```
val hierarchyDeps = taskKey[Seq[ModuleID]]("")
val hierarchyDepsImpl = Def.task {
  loadedBuild.value.allProjectRefs.flatMap { case (projectRef, resolvedProject) =>
    (projectRef / libraryDependencies).value
  }
}

val cmn = project.in(file("cmn"))
val subA = project.in(file("sub_a")).dependsOn(cmn).settings(hierarchyDeps := hierarchyDepsImpl.value)
val subB = project.in(file("sub_b")).dependsOn(cmn).settings(hierarchyDeps := hierarchyDepsImpl.value)
```

but getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for val projectRef: sbt.ProjectRef in List(value projectRef, value $anonfun, method $anonfun$hierarchyDepsImpl$1, value hierarchyDepsImpl, object $5879c5c8d08c0b0b007a, package <empty>, package <root>) (currentOwner= value hierarchyDepsImpl )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something outside of sbt philosophy.

You should define a task for each project that does something. Then add `aggregate` to your root project with the list of all sub-projects. Thus, when you call `sbt taskName`, it will call `taskName` for all sub-projects in `aggregate`.

Also, what you want to do can be just done with following

```sh
sbt "show libraryDependencies"
```

given that you defined `aggregate` for your root project

```
val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(cmn, subA, subB)
```